# Conditional Routing in Angular + Ionic template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am currently new to Angular Ionic Framework.

I have a screen where the user can see a list of items, where in he can tap on the item and view the details of the item on the screen. However there are certain items in the list which have multiple sub items in them. On tap of those items the user has to be redirected to a different screen which will display the sub list of items

[image]

Here in the above image the rows with yellow color have sub items in them, which should redirect the user to a screen A and the other item should redirect the user to screen B.

Questions 
 1. Is there a way to add **ng-if="alarm.status == 1" ng-href=" URL TO BE ADDED HERE " else ng-href=" URL TO BE ADDED HERE "** in ion-list directly or something similar?

Eg.

```
<ion-list >    
      <ion-item class="item-icon-right " ng-repeat="alarm in alarmList| filter: alarmName" type="item-text-wrap" ng-if="alarm.status == 1" ng-href=" URL TO BE ADDED HERE " else ng-href=" URL TO BE ADDED HERE " on-swipe-right="swipeRight()" on-swipe-left="acknoledge()" can-swipe="true">


        ....... 

      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
ng-href="{{ alarm.status == 1? oneURL : otherURL  }}"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you please tell me the way to pas parameters via url. eg  ng-href="{{ alarm.multiple == 1? '#/app/alarmSource' : '#/app/alarm/alarm.id'  }}"

Comment: Inside the curly brackets you are writing normal javascript, so you can do:  `'#/app/alarm/' + alarm.id`